# Stars in the symbols in clojure

Tags: clojure

Do stars have a specific meaning when used in defining symbols (such as in functions, bindings etc.)? Is it just a normal binding name when i define something like:

```
(def *clojure* "CLOJURE")
```

As i `def` this i get in the REPL:

Warning: *clojure* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *clojure* or change the name.

Where can i read learn more about the special characters and things like **?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By convention, variables with 'earmuffs' (i.e. enclosed by *s) are dynamic vars which can be rebound using [`binding`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/binding) and related functions e.g.

```
(def ^:dynamic *dyn*)

(binding [*dyn* "Hello world!"]
  (println *dyn*))
```

if you name a variable in this way without making it dynamic you get the warning you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

Check this [clojure style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide). Earmuffs are just one type of convention as already been mentioned by @Lee.